# Start a query activity using API

Tags: marketing-cloud

Does anyone have an example of how to start (run) a query activity using the API? I have been looking for awhile and can not find one good example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out (need to just set your qdObjectID). I tested and this does in fact start the query.

```
    QueryDefinition qd = new QueryDefinition();
    qd.ObjectID = qdObjectID;
    PerformResult[] pr = soapClient.Perform(
    new PerformOptions(),
    "start",
    new APIObject[] { qd },
    out OverallStatus, out OverallStatusMessage, out RequestID);
    return OverallStatus;
```

Answer (score 0):

Would a SOAP call suffice?  Have a look at the sample packets [here](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/technical_library/web_service_guide/technical_articles/performing_a_query_activity_using_the_soap_web_service_api/).

Comment: Do you know if there is a example of how to do this with the .net web service ?